# BlogEngine.NET - It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I am really not able to get the application working over IIS Express.

I am downloading this repo: https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET and I am placing on IIS DocumentRoot.

Then I give the proper permissions to the proper folders:

```
BlogEngine.NET-master\BlogEngine\BlogEngine.NET\AppData\
BlogEngine.NET-master\BlogEngine\BlogEngine.NET\Custom\
```

And then I try to access /admin, from the DocumentRoot (which is not possible), then I try:

```
https://localhost:8080/BlogEngine.NET-master/ -> 403
https://localhost:8080/BlogEngine.NET-master/admin -> 404
https://localhost:8080/BlogEngine.NET-master/BlogEngine/admin -> 404
https://localhost:8080/BlogEngine.NET-master/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/admin -> 500 (BlogEngine.NET - It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level)
https://localhost:8080/BlogEngine.NET-master/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/whaterver -> 500 (BlogEngine.NET - It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level)
```

I attach some pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have read some walktrhoughs about the web.config files duplicated but I see no web.config in my DocumentROOT and I am not a very acquainted with deploying .NET applications over IIS and I have spent time probably in the wrong direction for a maybe simple problem. I have also reported an issue in github but I received no response.

I hope that someone who knows how to deploy IIS .NET can help, really

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2006/11/22/virtual-application-vs-virtual-directory/

Comment: Thanks but reading that didn't really give me a solution, I cannot deploy it over IIS and that sucks. I had to do it in a Visual Studio Proyect, but that's noob

Comment: Read it again :-)